# jQuery Get Textbox ID From Loop Choosed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple textbox from loop.

```
$qComposition = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_SAC_TBL_COMPOSITION WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND COMPOSITIONID != 'CM0001' ORDER BY LIST_ORDER ASC");
oci_execute($qComposition);
while($dComposition = oci_fetch_array($qComposition))
{
?>
    <input type="text" class="inputText input<?php echo $dComposition['COMPOSITIONID']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $dComposition['COMPOSITION_NAME']; ?>" id="<?php echo $dComposition['COMPOSITIONID']; ?>" onkeypress="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="display: none;" disabled/>
<?php
}
```

Table `WA_SAC_TBL_COMPOSITION`:

```
COMPOSITIONID | COMPOSITION_NAME
CM0001        | Status Sheet
CM0002        | Accessories Sheet
CM0003        | Box P/N
CM0004        | Pack Label P/N
CM0005        | Name Label
CM0006        | Warranty Card
CM0007        | DVD Part No
CM0008        | AC Code
```

And the result display on HTML to be
[image]

Then I have selected specific `COMPOSITIONID` to be show. Table `WA_SAC_TBL_PRODUCT_COMPOSITION`, here is the data:

```
COMPOSITIONID_FK    PARTID_FK
CM0003              PA0001
CM0009              PA0001
CM0006              PA0001
CM0004              PA0001
CM0005              PA0001
CM0001              PA0001
```

As you can see `CM0002` is not registered on table.

Here is JS to get selected `COMPOSITIONID`

```
$('.listScan, .inputText').hide(); //To hide all textbox

var lenComposition = jsonStr.composition.length;

for(var i=0; i<lenComposition; i++)
{
    var composition = jsonStr.composition[i];

    $('#'+composition).show(); //To show only choosed textbox
    $('.input'+composition).attr('disabled', true);
}

var getTextboxID = $('input.inputText:eq(0)').attr('id');

alert(getTextboxID);
```

When I try to `alert(getTextboxID)`, it show me `CM0002`. As We know I didn't register it on choosed table. I know the JS get `CM0002` from `$qComposition` above.

But now I want JS get the ID only from choosed.

How to achieve that?